# Browser Testing on AppVeyor using Laravel Dusk

Tags: php, laravel, selenium-chromedriver, appveyor, laravel-dusk

I've been trying to set up my CI environment on AppVeyor since I need SQL Server. I can't seem to get laravel dusk working with it. I've managed to

- Install PHP
- Setup SQL Server 2012
- Install Composer and all the packages
- Install all my npm packages
- Install the PDO SQLSRV drivers

and run a small script to create the .env file for testing but when I finally run 
    php artisan dusk
there's like 4 errors and 1 failure out of my 5 assertions 
Here's an image of the tests failing: https://i.gyazo.com/98f3bc4ae979793eb4af62e97d90080d.png

The tests work on my local machine and I'm trying to automate it. I have no idea how to access my app while it's being tested so I've just put a localhost in the APP_URL of my environment configuration file(Laravel specific).

I'm trying to figure out how to get browser testing working on it. I've also installed chrome for chromedriver to be used in Dusk. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can connect to build VM with RDP (https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/) and debug. Also it would be good to see a repro in public repository to help more.